# Need to close a div when it is click on it but should not close when inner div is clicked

Tags: javascript

To be more clear When you run the code ----  click 'show' in the page  a div opens up with a gray background and another inner div with green background---onclick on gray background the div needs to close if we click on green div it should not close please help me out Thanks In advance.

I have a text 'show' onclick on show it open's up a div which is set to display=none and this div is set to `overflow=hidden`. Inside the div I have a another div with matter. This works fine but the issue is onclick of the main div which is set to display=none has to close when it is click in its area.

code:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<script language="javascript"> 
function toggle(tId) {
 var ele = document.getElementById(tId);
       ele.style.display = "block";
}
function cancelToggle(id,e)

      {         var target = (e && e.target) || (event && event.srcElement);
        var obj = document.getElementById('toggleText');
        if(target!=obj){obj.style.display='none'}
      }
</script>
<body>

 <a id="displayText" href="javascript:toggle('toggleText');">show</a>

 <div id="toggleText" style="display: none; background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);  
            bottom: 0; height: 100%; left: 0; overflow: hidden; position: fixed; right:100; top: 10; width: 100%;">

    <div style="background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #80C5A9; display: block; height: 40%;
                position:fixed; bottom: 0;  overflow: hidden; width: 100%;">
   <h1>Welcome Naren</h1>
   <label>Its good for u.All the best</label> 
  </div>
 </div>

 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work?

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <script language="javascript"> 
       function toggle(el) {
           if ( el.id && el.style.display == 'block' ) {
              el.style.display = 'none';
           } else {
              el.style.display = 'block';
           }
       }

    function cancelToggle(id,e)

         {         var target = (e && e.target) || (event && event.srcElement);
           var obj = document.getElementById('toggleText');
           if(target!=obj){obj.style.display='none'}
         }

    function stop() {
        if (event.stopPropagation) {
            event.stopPropagation();
        } else {
            window.event.cancelBubble = true;
        }
    }
    </script>
    <body>

    <a id="displayText" href="javascript:toggle(document.getElementById('toggleText'));">show</a>

    <div onClick='toggle(this)' id="toggleText" style="display: none; background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);  
               bottom: 0; height: 100%; left: 0; overflow: hidden; position: fixed; right:100; top: 10; width: 100%;">

       <div onClick='stop()' style="background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #80C5A9; display: block; height: 40%; position:fixed; bottom: 0;  overflow: hidden; width: 100%;">
      <h1>Welcome Naren</h1>
      <label>Its good for u.All the best</label> 
     </div>
    </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

The other option is to examine event.target and see if the click came from inside the inner div.

Comment: HTML example will not work for IE which uses window.event.cancelBubble

Comment: I am new to java script can u paste the complete working code.

Comment: I am getting a error in firefox event is undefined but works fine in other browsers.

Comment: function stop(e) {
        if (!e) {
   window.event.cancelBubble = true;
           
        } else {
             e.stopPropagation();
        }
    }  now it works <div onClick='stop(event)'></div>